# Add geometry to XYZ-tiles in .JPG format to serve in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, postgis, raster2pgsql, quickmapservices

I have a WMS service from a governmental website of my state. Using the QGIS plugin `QuickMapServices` and its function `Generate XYZ Tiles (Directory)` in the "Processing toolbox" I downloaded a set of tiles from this WMS up to the closest zoom level for a rather small area of a district, which is enough for my current use case but still includes several GB's of data.

These tiles are in jpg format and when I run `gdalinfo` on them I can see that they do not include any geometry information like an EPSG code or name of projection:

```
Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF
Files: 663.jpg
Size is 256, 256
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)
Upper Right (  256.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  256.0,  256.0)
Center      (  128.0,  128.0)
Band 1 Block=256x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 128x128
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

My use case now is that I need to serve the tiles for an offline app and to reduce the load of tiles that need to be downloaded I would like to

1. add my raster to my already existent PostGIS database using `raster2pgsql`
2. Check which cells of each zoom level intersects with a specific PostGIS line feature
3. Create a table of raster cell id's that is used in my API when a request comes in for downloading tiles on that line feature

**Question**

However, my biggest problem now is that I do not know how to add the geometry to my geometryless .jpg tiles in PostGIS to perform the necessary `ST_Intersects` check. Does anybody know how to do that?

Also, if anybody has other ideas how to solve my main issue of providing less tiles offline I would be glad for any assistance!